# Array Declaration and pointer assignment in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax

I am confused in the basics of pointer and array declaration in C. I want to know the difference between following two statements except that base address to array is assigned to ptr in seconed statement.

```
int a[2][3]= { (1,2,3),(4,5,6)};
int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0];
```

Please quote examples to clarify.
What effect do [3] on R side of line 2 has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know operator precedence rules in C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedencehttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

`int (*ptr)[3]` as opposed to `int * ptr [3]`

The first one is a pointer (notice * is closer to the var name) to arrays of int of size 3
The second one is equal to `int (*(ptr [3]))` which is an array of size 3 on int pointers.

You can also use this site: http://cdecl.org/ if you have doubts on how to interpret an expression.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Bidimensional array:**

```
int a[2][3]= { {1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

With this statement in memory you have 2x3 integers, all adjacent in memory.I suppose that you know how to access them, but in the case you don't I'll clarify it:

```
a[0][0] : 1
a[0][1] : 2
a[0][2] : 3
a[1][0] : 4
a[1][1] : 5
a[1][2] : 6
```

**2. Pointer to array:**

```
int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0];
```

ptr points to a int[3] block of memory.So you can assign it only to an int[3] type:

```
ptr= &a[0];
ptr= &a[1];
```

The difference is that this pointer does not have it's own memory, and you have to assign it to an int[3] variable or allocate it:

```
ptr= malloc (2*sizeof(int[3]);
```

This way you can use the memory pointed by ptr, if you initialize ptr this way:

```
for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
        ptr[j][i]=i+j*3+1;
```

This case you'll have the same memory representation of int a[2][3], except that this memory is in the heap and not in the stack.You can always choose to realloc/free the memory and this memory is not deleted once your function terminates.

Answer (score -1):

a is 2-D array of row size 2 and column size 3.

whereas `ptr` is pointer to an array of `int` having size 3

But your array `a`initialization is not in correct manner

Since you have used `()` so comma operator will be in effect and will initialize with `3`and `6` and other elements of array `a` will be `0` to do actual initialization use `{}`

&a[0] is address of first element of array (means it will print same value for a also).

but this `&a[0]` comes into effect when you perform pointer arithmetic operation on `ptr`

In case of array there are 3 things to keep in mind :

---> `int *ptr=&a[0][0];` Address of first element `ptr++` will give you next element `a[0][1]`

---> &a[0] = address of first element but if you do `int (*ptr)[3]=&a[0]` 
then by doing `ptr++` pointer will be increased by the size of whole row and ptr will point to next row directly means now ptr will point to `&a[1]`

---> &a = address of whole array and if you keep it in `int (*ptr)[2][3] =&a` and do `ptr++` pointer will be increased by the size of whole array.

Comment: what about assignment to &a[0]. @Omkant

Comment: @MohitSehgal: I think you got it

Comment: the address of the first element of `a` is `&a[0]`

Comment: @newacct: then what is this `int *ptr = &a[0][0]` ? can you please elaborate

Comment: @Omkant: that is the address of the first element of the first element of `a`

Comment: If suppose `a` is statring at `0xabcdef` address then `a`, `&a` , `&a[0]` ,`&a[0][0]` will print the same `0xabcdef` or not ?